# Classma or classmate in spoken English

Tags: spoken-english

An American tutor said you should say classma(omit t) rather than classmate in spoken English.  An Irish teacher told me you should never omit t in spoken English, such as but, as it is considered to be illiterate. Who is right? Soulmate deskmate.

Comment: No, don't omit word final consonants. That "American" tutor is wrong. I am curious what your native language is, because usually people whose native tongues don't have certain consonant endings have troubling learning languages with such consonants, e.g. English.

Comment: My native language is Madarin. I have no problem  with ending consonants.

Comment: Several modern Chinese varieties, including Mandarin, have lost a lot of consonant endings that some other dialects of Chinese have retained, e.g. /t/ /p/ (dental/alveolar/bilabial plosives) and a lot others. This is just a linguistic aspect about those languages/dialects. Mandarin doesn't have a lot of consonant endings that occur in other languages including English. ([Mandarin phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology)) It's good that you personally don't have trouble pronouncing ending consonants, which means you shouldn't omit them to begin with.

Comment: Your American teacher probably meant that the final [t] is not released, but the oral configuration is still there. The same thing happens in many Southern Chinese dialects.

Comment: I suspect the American was trying to make a subtle point that has been lost in the telling. Unless and until you have a chance to discuss it more fully with them I would ignore it.

Comment: I suspect the American was trying to explain that we often substitute a glottal stop for a **t** in this word.